# Doxygen: grouping classes in several nested groups

Tags: c++, doxygen

I intend to include some documented C++ classes (let say `AClass`) within a Doxygen group (let say `GROUP_C`), while that group is into another one (let say `GROUP_B`), and that second group into another, base one (let say `GROUP_A`). Like this:

```
/** \addtogroup GROUP_A */
/** @{ */

/** \defgroup GROUP_B */
/** @{ */

/** \defgroup GROUP_C */
/** @{ */

/// Comment
class AClass
{
};

/** @} */

/** @} */ 
/** @} */
```

I'm trying to get a clean and logical documentation for that situation, but, as simple as I see it, I have not been able to found anything more specific than the Doxygen official documentation, where nothing is said about any cyclical grouping problems. However, just doxygen-ing the simple code above, such problems occur:

```
warning: Refusing to add group GROUP_C to group GROUP_B, since the latter is already a subgroup of the former
```

I also get strange breadcrumbs indications of the generated module under the `AClass` documentation:

[image]

Does anybody know what am I understanding wrong in the nesting-group system of Doxygen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot: I'm using doxygen v1.8.8 in Debian Jessie. I need the above structure in my file because I plan to include other classes in `GROUP_B` (that are not in `GROUP_C`) and in `GROUP_A` (that are not in `GROUP_B`). I also have tested changing `\addtogroup` in the first line by `\defgroup` and got the same error.

Comment: Now, I have avoided the error by adding a new element just after the definition of `GROUP_B`, for instance, a class. What explanation is there for that behavior?

Answer (score 5):

This solution has been working for me for many years since old versions of Doxygen:

```
/** \defgroup GROUP_A My top-level group description
  *
  * Put here a longer description.
  *
  **/

/** @addtogroup GROUP_B  My group B description
  * \ingroup GROUP_A
  *  @{ */

  // classes, etc.

  /** @} */


/** @addtogroup GROUP_C  My group C description
  * \ingroup GROUP_B
  *  @{ */

  // classes, etc.


  /** @} */
```

Comment: Thanks, Jose Luis!  Certainly that works :)  I have some issues still when there is no content in GROUP_B, but that is less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your given example works as expected on doxygen-1.8.8 and on latest master git branch. The warning does not appear. 
Is it possible you are including other source files (than the presented example code) into your test run and that other files contain conflicting \defgroup or \addgroup statements that cause the circles in the group structure?

Regarding that "GROUP_A" doubling line below "AClass Class Reference" - I guess that is simply a doxygen bug.

Comment: Mmm... I have just copied the code above in a new .h file in a clean folder (only that file, thus no conflicts with other files contents) and then I run doxygen. The problem appears again :(  In this screenshot you can see all the steps:  goo.gl/5KX9tb